# -Wall: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling, gcc, c

im trying to compile two files on my bash : Main.c , DB.c 
this is how i compiled them and they gave me no errors : gcc -c Main.c  DB.c` 
so they should have created Main.o and DB.o . 
now im trying to compile Main.o and DB.o :  -Wall Main.o DB.o
but when im trying to compile these the bash gives me that -Wall: command not found

anyone encountered this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Wall` isn't a command<sup>1</sup>, it's an option (show all warnings) to the `gcc` command. From `man gcc`

```
   -Wall
       This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users
       consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to
       prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros.  This also
       enables some language-specific warnings described in C++ Dialect
       Options and Objective-C and Objective-C++ Dialect Options.
```

To link your object files to produce an executable `a.out` , you need

```
gcc Main.o DB.o
```

or (to give an alternative executable name `myprog`)

```
gcc -o myprog  Main.o DB.o
```

Alternatively, compile and link in a single command (with warnings)

```
gcc -Wall -o myprog Main.c DB.c
```

---

[1]. `wall` is - but that's something completely unrelated

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and the information , it really worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to build and compile like this:

gcc filename.c -o outputFile_name
./outputFile_name

And do this for the two files separately. The following file should compile with the name "outputFile_name" after it has been followed by -o

Comment: thank you for helping me , it was really helpful taking me to the solution :)